# Missing namespace but have the dlls in the component folder

Tags: visual-studio-2017, namespaces, nuget

I've got 2 version of an old c# project.

One of the projects builds just fine.

The other is getting this error when trying to build and publish it.

I have the dlls in the component folder

I've tried installing a nuget package that I found.

[image]

Comment: Hi Theory, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps,  please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the current nuget package `GrapeCity.ActiveReports` version **15.0.7** does not support your project `TargetFramework 4`. It at least >= `net framework 4.6.2`

[image]

To solve it:

**1)** upgrade TargetFramework version of your project

right-click on the **Project Properties**-->**Application**--> change **TargetFrameworks** to `Net Framework 4.6.2`.

Then, install the package again.